# Using XcodeGen with build tool plug-ins

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcodegen

I built a Swift Package that contains a plugin defined as a `.buildTool()`. I would like to use it in a project where we create the project via XcodeGen. I couldn't find a way to configure the `YAML` so that the named Swift Package is set under *Run Build Tool Plug-ins* in the *Build Phases*.

Has anyone had any experience with this, any help is highly appreciated?

Comment: I have same problem( If you have resolved it can you get me know please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76163290/how-to-add-r-swift-into-xcodegen-project

Comment: @Sergey There's already an open issue on GitHub. Let's see when it's finished. https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/issues/1290

Comment: It's finally merged: https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/releases/tag/2.37.0

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible in [2.37.0](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/releases/tag/2.37.0).
Very similar to declaring regular dependencies:

```
buildToolPlugins:
  - plugin: Plugin_name
    package: Package_name
```

Comment: So good. I have been following the issue since the beginning.