# How to add R.swift into XcodeGen project?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, xcodegen, r.swift

I'm experimenting with XcodeGen, and ran into a problem. I can't add "R.Swift" dependency. Not through SPM not through CocoaPods(

In the case of SPM, I don't understand how to add Run Build Tool Plug-in "RswiftGeneratesInternalResources (Swift)" into target/Build Phases

In the case of Cocoapods in R.generated.swift file an error appears "No such module 'Rswift'

Can anyone help me and show correct way how I can add R.swift into XcodeGen project?

Comment: The docs tell you what to do: https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift#xcode-project---spm

Answer (score 1):

Here is my project.yml. (with cocoapods, not spm.)

```
targets:
  MyApp:
    type: application
    platform: iOS 
    sources:
      - MyApp
    preBuildScripts:
      - name: Generate R.swift
        script: |
          "$PODS_ROOT/R.swift/rswift" generate "$SRCROOT/MyApp/R.generated.swift"
        basedOnDependencyAnalysis: false
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I just moved to [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen)) It turned out to be much easier to work with it in the XcodeGen project.

Answer (score 0):

XcodeGen support Build Tool Plugin since 2.37.0.

```
packages:
  Rswift:
    url: https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift
    from: 7.4.0
```

```
targets:
  MyApp:
    ...
    dependencies:
      - package: Rswift
        product: RswiftLibrary
    buildToolPlugins:
      - plugin: RswiftGenerateInternalResources
        package: Rswift
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

To add R.swift to Xcodegen using SPM, you can do the following steps:

- Download released R.swift package from https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift/releases. Extract downloaded .zip file, copy `rswift` file and place it in the directory where your `.xcodeproj` file lives, eg. `scripts/rswift`
- Open the `project.yml` file and declare R.swift as a dependency. Make sure to add `RswiftLibrary` as the package's product.
- Modify the build Run script with the following changes:

> "$SRCROOT/scripts/rswift" generate "$SRCROOT/R.generated.swift"

By following these steps, you can integrate R.swift into Xcodegen using SPM.